# yarn command not found in gitlab ci

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, yarnpkg

I am trying to configure my gitlab-ci to use `yarn install` instead of `npm install`

My current gitlab-ci.yml looks like:

```
image: node:6.9.4

cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/
  - .yarn

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -qy libelf1

stages:
  - test

test_core:
  stage: test
  script:
  - yarn config set cache-folder .yarn
  - yarn install
  - npm run build
  - npm run test
  tags:
    - 2gb
```

But the build fails with the error: 
`/bin/bash: line 48: yarn: command not found`

is there something I am missing?
I tried installing yarn with:

`curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash`

this gave me same error, probably because I need to reload the bash environment for the yarn command to become available.

The above config works perfect with `npm install`.

Please help me resolve this. If there is something missing in my config file or there is something wrong with the gitlab-ci.
Thanks.

Comment: Please just try following the instructions for Debian installation: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#linux-tab and then post the results. So far it's failing because you haven't installed it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solved it by using the latest official node docker image.
Since image: `6.10.0`, yarn is installed by default in the image.

But if you need `node-gyp` to build any package, it needs to be installed by adding a line to the script:

`yarn global add node-gyp`

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your ci script after yarn got installed:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.yarn/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: In my case, I had a custom location set for npm packages so that they could be installed globally without `sudo`. Exporting the path at the beginning of my commands fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I use `image:node:latest` and sometimes it prompts the error. `Clear Runner Caches` do the job for me. Maybe the runner did not recover to the correct state after doing other jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using `npx` (package runner). It's better then extending docker-image only for this purpose

```
npx yarn someCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the shell not knowing the path to yarn
In the home folder for gitlab-runner you need to add the path to yarn in the startup files
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html

Just add "export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/yarn" at the end of your startup files